# AngularJs directive templateURL in Laravel5.2

Tags: laravel-5, angular-directive

I want to use angular directive in my **laravel project**. But when I try to call my angular directive, **tempateUrl of Angular Directive** is not found. My Code is given below:

**html**

```
 <demographich-url></demographich-url>
```

**JS**

```
 .directive('demographichUrl', [function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            replace: true,
            templateUrl: 'demographich', // this doesn't work
            // 'templateUrl: './views/comments/comment-form.html', // this doesn't work
           // 'templateUrl: './views/comments/comment-form.blade.php', // this doesn't work
            // template:'<h1> hello world! </h1>',  // this works
        };
    }])
```

**Laravel Routes**

```
   // routes
  Route::get('demographich', 'CompanyController@demographich');


   // controller
    public function demographich()
   {
       return view('comments.comment-form');
   }
```

**  comment-form.blade.php ( templateUrl page [ this page not found ] )**

```
    <h1> Hi your comments goes here!!!!  </h1>
```

** My file structure **

```
 |
 | ---  resources
        | --- views
              | -- comments
                    | -- comment-form.blade.php
```

**NB:** 
Laravel : **5.2**
Angular: **1.5.X**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved this problem using below directive code.

```
.directive('demographichUrl', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {
            obj: '=',
            submitFunc: '&'
        },
        templateUrl:  '<?= asset('app/directive/demograph/demographich.html') ?>',
        link: function (scope, iElement, iAttrs) {

        }
    };
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use laravel blade page in directive..

```
.directive('surveyHeader', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {
            obj: '=',
            submitSurveyheader: '&'
        },
        templateUrl:  '<?php echo asset('app/directive/surveyheader/surveyheader.blade.php') ?>',

        link: function (scope, iElement, iAttrs) {

        }
    };
})
```